# How do we know we have all subsets of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

The axiom schema of comprehension basically says that every definable subclass of a set is also a set. However, we know there are only countably many formulas in the language of set theory. So, this axiom seems to only give us countably many subsets of a set. Intuitively, this seems like a very bad result since we know there should be way more subsets of large cardinalities than this. Intuitively, I want ALL subsets of a set to exist, regardless of whether or not they are nameable by some formula. So, my main first question is how to alleviate the worry that we are missing on lots of different subsets of a set, and therefore our math may think the power set of a set is way smaller than it should be. My second side question is that given that the axiom of comprehension only seems to give us countably many subsets of a set, where do all the other subsets come from? We can prove that the powerset of the natural numbers is not countable, and of course I understand that formal proof. Maybe there is nothing more to say about this than just pointing at the proof, but some explanation as to what generates these subsets, given that the real thing that we want generating these subsets (namely their mere existence rather than definability) is not generating these subsets.

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of the [power set axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_power_set)?

Comment: I don't think so - my question is asking whether there's a mismatch about what ZFC thinks the subsets of a particular set are and what are the "real" subsets of a set. The power set axiom just collects all the sets which ZFC thinks are subsets into one set.

Comment: But Cantor's theorem is a theorem of ZFC.  In particular, ZFC proves that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable, hence contains elements which are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ yet not definable, i.e. not of the form $\{x \in \mathbb{N} : \varphi(x)\}$.  So I would say Comprehension only gets you the definable subsets, but Power Set gets you the rest.

Comment: How do we know it gets all the rest? All we know is that it gets some undefinable subsets.

Comment: @DavidBuiles What exactly do you mean by "all the rest"? As far as the model is concerned it has all of the subsets that there are.

Comment: It seems the only way to say this isn't a real question is to say: (1) "there exist some numbers xx such that our conception does not definitely fix whether those numbers form a set or not." But if it is part of our conception that (2) "for any numbers xx, they form a set", then the only way for the first statement to be indeterminate is for the notion of what it is to be a number to be indeterminate, which seems implausible. So, given (1) is false, the question seems to have meaning.

Comment: (Here I'm focusing on the case of subsets of the natural numbers. And I'm assuming our conception of the natural numbers (and of sets) outstrips the particular axioms we are using, evidenced by Godel sentences for example.)

Comment: Do you know about Skolem's paradox?

Comment: Of course! I'm also aware of Putnam's cool "model-theoretic argument against realism" using the paradox in the philosophy of language :) Is that your way of saying that we know ZFC doesn't guarantee the existence of all subsets of a set? I basically knew it didn't, but what I'm really interested in is if there is any way to address this deficiency. I'm thinking that this simple worry is at the heart of many independence results in set theory. Several logicians/philosophers have said that CH is indefinite since the power set operation is "inherently vague" (Feferman and Field).